# Scale in opposite direction - What is it called?

Tags: piano, scales, terminology

Right hand plays ascending scale, left hand plays descending scale, then alternate until the origin.

Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ABRSM examination syllabus calls them Contrary-motion scales - for example, see the Scales section on this page: https://us.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/piano/piano-grade-3/

Answer (score 0):

it's called contrary motion scale or simply: split scale or parting scale